# Changing the style (opacity) of multiple images using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, styles

I am trying to get multiple elements, that are organised under 3 arrays "tops", "bottoms", "shoes".

I know I can grab multiple objects using the

```
document.getElementsByClassName("class1 class2");
```

How do I change the style for each of those objects, my current code is: (I have tried both visibility and opacity, but it keep getting a uncaught type error because the document.getelements.... isn't returning anything.

```
function filter() {
var this_id = event.target.id;
console.log(this_id);
if (this_id = "filtertops") {
    document.getElementsByClassName("a4 a7 a11 a12 a8").style.visibility="hidden"; //not tops
    document.getElementsByClassName("a1 a2 a3 a5 a9 a10 a14").style.visbility="visible"; // tops
    }
else if (this_id = "filterbottoms") {
    document.getElementsByClassName("a2 a3 a5 a10 a14 a8").style.opacity="0.4"; //not bottoms
    document.getElementsByClassName("a1 a4 a7 a9 a11 a12").style.opacity="1"; //bottoms
    }
else if (this_id = "filtershoes") {
    document.getElementsByClassName("a1 a2 a3 a4 a5 a7 a9 a10 a11 a12 14").style.opacity="0.4"; //not shoes
    document.getElementsByClassName("a8").style.opacity="1"; //shoes
    }
```

I tried assigning them to a variable as well and then a for loop to change the style of each object, but that didnt work either.

```
function filterbottoms() {
    var nonbottom = document.getElementsByClassName("a2 a3 a5 a10 a14 a8");
    var bottoms = document.getElementsByClassName("a1 a4 a7 a9 a11 a12");
    for (i in bottoms)
        {
            i.style.visibility='visible';
        }
    for (i in nonbottom)
        {
            i.style.visibility='hidden';
        } 

}
```

Comment: CSS class names mustn't start with a number, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/448981/what-characters-are-valid-in-css-class-names

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were close with the `for` loop:

```
for (i in bottoms){
    bottoms[i].style.visibility='visible';
}
```

should `<edit>`but won't`</edit>` work. On each iteration `i` is the next *key,* not the next *value*.

But you should use a conventional `for` rather than a `for..in`:

```
for (var i = 0; i < bottoms.length; i++){
    bottoms[i].style.visibility='visible';
}
```

EDIT: I recommended a conventional `for` loop because using `for..in` is generally not appropriate for arrays or array-like objects as (depending on the particular object) it will iterate over non-numeric properties. Joseph's comment confirms that in this case a `for..in` will definitely not work for that reason.

Comment: actually the first will not work because of the for...in syntax.  When looping through nodeList objects, they have a length attribute that then complains about not having a style attribute.  The second one you provided should work.

Comment: Thanks Joseph - answer updated a little. (Obviously I recommended a conventional for loop on the principle that that sort of thing _might_ happen, but I had not bothered to check if it would definitely be a problem for NodeLists.)

Comment: The `document.getElementsByClassName("class1 class2");` is returned `[]`. Do you know why this is?

Comment: Presumably because your document doesn't have any elements that have both of those classes, so no elements are returned.

Comment: doesn't it return all the elements that are in class1 or class 2 or class3 etc etc? because I have checked the images and they do have the relevant classes

Comment: I believe it returns only the elements that have _all_ of the specified classes, i.e., it is an AND, not an OR. That's what [MDN says](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.getElementsByClassName)...

Comment: oh, can you recommend another method?